# Plone content type works as folder but not as event

Tags: python, plone

I have been trying to create a new content type for Plone based on the event type.  I followed this [tutorial](http://weblog.kernelcode.com/2009/09/29/creating-a-content-type-for-plone-3-x/) for making content types and successfully created [this code](http://codepad.org/iUFnhAZW) for my own content type called "Multimedia".  My code works, however the type is based on the folder type.

My attempts to change this to be based on the event type:

1. Lines 6, 14 and 40 all contain instances of folder or ATFolder
2. Looking on the plone site I found that the event type is [event and ATEvent](http://api.plone.org/Plone/2.1.1/public/ATContentTypes.content.event-module.html), I think.
3. I replaced all the occurrences of folder with event(I had previously replaced all occurrences of base with folder and it worked)

Unfortunately this just throws a huge stack error that I cant find the relevance to my script in, I looked also in the error log but there is no reference to any lines in Multimedia.py so I am stuck.

If anyone knows how to change my current code to correct code that would make Multimedia be based on the event type I would be very greatful for you help.

Regards

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend ATEvent in that way and will have to use [SchemaExtender](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.schemaextender) to do so

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a go tonight with this :)